# Como hacer que determinadas funciones de un archivo javascript solo se ejecuten dependiendo de la pagina html en la que se encuentre el usuario

Tags: javascript, html

Mi problema es que tengo un fichero denominado 'main.js' en este tengo todas las funciones, objetos, variables, etc... Que uso en mi pagina web. El problema es que todas las variables funciones y demas se ejecutan siempre en todas las paginas lo que lleva a errores, quiero saber cual es la mejor manera para que cada codigo se ejecute en la pagina que le corresponde. como digo el script de main.js esta linkeado en todas las paginas, pero quiero que cada fragmento de codigo se ejecute donde debe.

Comment: Parti tu archivo en archivos mas chicos y agrega solo los que necesites...

Comment: y tener muchos archivos no podria afectar de manera negativa a la optimizacion, velocidad de carga, o algo por el estilo?

Comment: Todo eso, ya lo estas haciendo cuando mandas un solo archivo gigante con un monton de cosas que no necesitas... no?

Comment: no lo sabia, entonces siempre que sea posible seria mejor enlazar un archivo con lo justo y necesario, verdad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes recoger parámetros o fragmentos de la url en cuestión mediante una sencilla función de javascript o, como en el ejemplo que te comparto, de **jquery** para con esa información especificar cuando quieres que se ejecute la función que necesitas recuperar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("tu-fragmento-url") > -1) {
      funcionEjecutada();
    }
  });
</script>
```

En este caso se identifica un "fragmento" de la url que coinciden con lo entrecomillado en el **indexOf** y al localizarlo le pedimos que ejecute la función **funcionEjecutada()**.

Otra opción sería separar y diferenciar cada una de esas funciones en función de las necesidades de cada **html** y ejecutarlas en **js** independientes cargándolos en he **header** de cada página bien en llamadas a otros archivos tipo **<script src="./loquesea.js>**  o bien en funciones directamente cargadas en ese html como en el ejemplo que arriba puedes ver.